# Rails app connect to twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am new Rails developer. Right now, I can let user register in my Rails App. I have database running also.

Todo:
After user register. I will ask permission to access his twitter. And I can access his tweets(including location information in tweets).

About this part, I have no idea how to do now? Can anyone give some links where I should start? I guess first step is I need authentication from twitter right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, first of all you need authentication user from twitter: [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth). Then you will find all methods there [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs)